# How to separate each results page in table when user search for more than one product?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, try to find the products when the user is searching.

```
 if ($Results.find("product").length > 0)
 {
   var $theProduct = null;
   var $id = vars['searchTerm'];

   //Search for each product        
   $Results.find("product").each(function() {

     if ($Results.find('id').text() === $id)
     {
       $theResult = $(this);    
     }
   });
```

From this point my search results display in table

```
   // Get the product data into the variables from the matched product
   var id = $theResult.find("id").text();
   var top = $theResult.attr("top-level-category");
   var sub = $theResult.attr("sub-level-category");
   var title = $theResult.find("title").text();
   var brand = $theResult.find("brand").text();
   var price = $theResult.find("price").text();

    //Results goes to table                         
   $('#search_table').append("<tr><td>" + 
     id + "</td><td>" + 
     top + "</td><td>" +
     sub + "</td><td>" + 
     title + "</td><td>" +
     brand + "</td><td>&pound" + 
     price + "</td></tr>");                     
   });
 }
```

When no search results find

```
else{
  // We don't have any results
  $("#mainBody").find("table").hide();
  $("#mainBody").append("<h3>There are no search results. </h3>"); 
}
```

The problem i have now is when the user try to find more than one product one my page, my code breaks and i do not know why.

My html:

```
<div id="mainBody">
            <table id="search_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Code</th>   
                        <th>Product Category</th>  
                        <th>Product Type</th>  
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: breaks how? You get an error? Unexpected behaviour? You'll need to explain a bit more. And also "try to find more than one product" - it's not clear what this means in relation to your code. You mean that the length of `$Results` is > 1? Or the user typed in some specific thing? Again please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, following on from my comment above...now I've formatted your code to be readable, with proper indentation, the problem becomes much more obvious. You run a `.each()` loop over the products inside Results, but all you do within the loop is assign a value to `$theResult`. Then you do nothing with it. Next time the loop runs, the value is over-written.

Then after the loop finishes, you start to try to use $theResult to append results to your table. But since you placed that code outside the loop, it will only run once, and will only ever use whatever the last value of $theResult happened to be - the value it was assigned the last time the loop executed.

This won't be a problem as long as there's only one item in $Results, but as soon as there are multiple items it'll be an issue. The fix is very simply to move all the code which interacts with `$theResult` inside your loop, so it will execute as many times as there are matching products:

```
$Results.find("product").each(function() {

 if ($Results.find('id').text() === $id)
 {
   $theResult = $(this);    

   // Get the product data into the variables from the matched product
   var id = $theResult.find("id").text();
   var top = $theResult.attr("top-level-category");
   var sub = $theResult.attr("sub-level-category");
   var title = $theResult.find("title").text();
   var brand = $theResult.find("brand").text();
   var price = $theResult.find("price").text();

   //Results goes to table                         
   $('#search_table').append("<tr><td>" + 
     id + "</td><td>" + 
     top + "</td><td>" +
     sub + "</td><td>" + 
     title + "</td><td>" +
     brand + "</td><td>&pound" + 
     price + "</td></tr>");                     
   });
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution because this has solve my problem. The only problem i have now is that my table is not display properly.  Maybe i have to check my result table?

Comment: No worries. However I don't know what you mean by "properly". What does it show, and what did you expect it to show instead? This is similar to my comment on the question, above - saying something doesn't work or isn't proper is not a sufficient description to allow people to know what the problem is.

Comment: When i said "properly" i mean that my table is not display.  I do not get any problems with my code but when i search for more than 1 product, my table is not display.

Comment: Ok...and it works properly if you have only one product in the results? Because the code above will loop through $Results as many times as there are items in results, it makes no difference if there is 1 item or 100, so I don't see how that is possible, unless there is some other code which is affecting things. For instance I assume that `$('#search_table')` represents an element `<table id="search_table">` and that this element exists in the DOM when the above code runs, but I can't see your HTML to prove it.

Comment: Yeah, when i search for one product is works properly. I will edit the post so you can see what my html looks like.

Comment: Ok you really need to append your rows to the table body, since you've defined it. i.e. you need to write this: `$('#search_table tbody').append(...`

Comment: I have made the change but nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see how this code can work when there's one result, but not when there are multiple results. It's not possible, unless there is something odd about your data structure. What is the actual content of $Results in the example where it doesn't work? It's tricky to know what's going on without seeing the source data

Comment: For example, when user search is need to be like: 0001 + 0002 (the ids of two products). I use this code in my js: hash[1] = encodeURIComponent(hash[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

Comment: Ok but that's what you're _sending_ to the server. My answer (and your original question) is related to dealing with what is _received_. I have no idea how these two things are connected, and your information doesn't answer my question. Here's another good question: have you verified that my code above is even being executed when you search for more than one product? Did you set a breakpoint on it? I am wondering if your program does something different when there is more than one product in the search terms (but of course it's only a guess because I can't see the rest of your code).

Comment: The code is executed properly with no errors but the table is not display. I was thinking instance of using "if", i try to changed it to "for". What do you think?

Comment: I have no idea. Try it and see. It seems unlikely to be the problem. You're already within a loop of the "product" object. And that still doesn't answer my question. I'll try again one more time... **What is the content of the $Results object when the above code is being executed?**

Comment: The content of the $Results is a list of products that have some variables inside like price, brand, title etc. This products are displayed in table as we discussed before.

Comment: Also the $Results is an xml dom tree that takes the products from php file.

Comment: I know in principle what is is, what I want to know is the **exact contents** at the time when you're running this code and experiencing the problem. Show me the **actual, real XML**. The most likely issue here is a mismatch between the XML structure and the code which is trying to use it.

Comment: Sorry for the late update but i manage to get it done. Thanks for your time.